# How do you swap two integer variables without using any if conditions, casting, or additional variables?

Tags: swap

There are two integer variables. Can you swap those integer variables without using any if conditions, without casting, and without using additional variables? For example:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
```

`a > b` always. The answer should be `a == 5` and `b == 10`

Comment: No, I have no idea how to slow down a problem or make it go faster.

Comment: seems to be a homework assignment if that's the case you should tag it as such

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable

Comment: can u solve this problem

Comment: Isn't it lovely, when someone upvotes a homework duplicate? :P

Comment: definately not a homework - too complex for that. OK for interview.

Comment: Just out of interest from somebody from another camp, is a solution like `list($a, $b) = array($b, $a)` possible in C#?

Comment: reminds me a ruby a,b = b,a solution  :) (its arrays)

Comment: I see no indication of language here, so it can't be answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you think you are being **clever** by not using 3rd variable then do some performance tests and you see that the much faster way is to use 3rd `int` to store the variable temporarily.

Anyways, i solved the problem with XOR bitwise operator:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Comment: More about swapping with xor is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: This fails to work if `a == b`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Axoren: no, it does not fail.

Comment: My mistake. It fails if `a` and `b` are references to the same variable, not if they're the same value. For example: `int c; int *a = &c; int *b = &c;`. In this case, `*a ^= *b` will cause both `*a` and `*b` to become 0 at the same time, leading to the value being lost. This is still important to note if attempting to implement a swap method that works with the variable's addresses.

Comment: In fact, all of the answers to this question fail under that case. I think that should be part of an interview question.

Comment: Your example "fails" because you have the variables pointing to same memory location. This is not in the scope of question

Answer (score 11):

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a little trick.

```
int a = 5;
int b= 10;
a = a+b;
b = a-b; /* Really (a+b) - b i.e. a */
a = a-b; /* Really (a+b) - a i.e. b */
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can do it By using plus/minus  operation.

```
Example:
num1 = num1 + num2;                
num2 = num1 - num2;                
num1 = num1 - num2;
```

Comment: Better to use addition/subtraction to avoid overflows and rounding problems.  That said, it's better to just use a temp variable, but still.

Comment: Multiply/Divide does not work if num2 is 0.

Comment: thanks for the info ans updated now

Answer (score 3):

```
a=a+b
b=a-b
a=a-b
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

simple try this

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

and that's it