# With less memory usage need to reorder the array elements

Tags: java

I have a recent interview question, reordering of elements in an array with minimum memory usage. Not to use any additional variable or collections etc.

#### input:

```
value   65 7 1 68 90
index    0 1 2  3  4
```

#### output:

```
value   90 68 1 7 65
index    0  1 2 3  4
```

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry not getting what you are saying

Comment: I'm not seeing the pattern here.  Is this sorted in any way or just arbitrary order?

Comment: @tieTYT values are reversed

Comment: @developer. By re-ordering, do you mean reversing?

Comment: you can see, index 4 values is shifted to 0 and viseversa

Comment: Luis meant insertion sort - not search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort and your output is NOT ordered...

Comment: here inder 0 is moved to index 4 and index1 is moved to index 3 and vise versa, there followed some pattren

Comment: I know this might be too obvious, but why not simply loop through the array and swap values ? Is this "too much memory" ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: If you have lets say `int a=1, b=2;` then after `b=a+0*(a=b);` `a=2` and `b=1`. But it is hard to say if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: i given answer as , have one more index in the same object and move the values using this extra index, it not impressed. Does my answer is correct

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov how do you swap without creating a temp variable?

Comment: @tieTYT look at the answers with the XOR.

Comment: @dimitardimitrov Bit manipulation

Comment: @MohammadS. Yeah :) Honestly, if I see this in production I'd rewrite the hell out of it ! :)

Comment: @dimitardimitrov I agree with you.  This is one of those memory efficient questions that don't consider the readability of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `XOR` to swap between elements (first with last, second with second from the end, etc) as follows:

```
int [] arr = {65, 7, 1, 68, 90};
for(int i=0; i<arr.length/2; i++){
    // the following 3 lines swap between elements arr[i] and arr[arr.length-i-1]
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length-i-1];
    arr[arr.length-i-1] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length-i-1];
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[arr.length-i-1];
}

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
90 68 1 7 65
```

Comment: Well if we are completely strict *i* is a variable.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is swapping array elements without using temp variable. You can make use of `XOR(^)` operation like this:

For swapping `a` and `b`:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
a ^= b
b ^= a
a ^= b
```

Now, you just need to iterate over the array from `index = 0` to `index = length / 2`, and swap elements at beginning and end.

Comment: The temporary values have to stored somewhere, so this won't use less memory than using a temporary variable.

Comment: @FDinoff. How would that make any difference?

Comment: See http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2013/02/swap-two-numbers-without-third-temp-variable-java-program-example-tutorial.html

Comment: @Joni. I don't think the temporary results will be stored in any temporary variable. The result is directly assigned to existing variable. Check the byte code using `javap`.

Comment: The temporary result of XOR will be stored in a register, just like a temporary variable. You can check this by disassembling the output of the JIT compiler; byte code does not really tell you what the program is going to execute.

Comment: @Joni. Can you tell me how to disassemble the output of JIT compiler? I would really like to see what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole :) http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2013/06/printing-generated-assembly-code-from.html

Comment: @Joni. Thank you so much. That is simply precious. But I see no Windows version there. I guess I need to open my Ubuntu now. :)

Comment: More info here, with a link  to download the disassembler plugin for Windows x86: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly

Comment: @Joni. Thanks :) Was going through that link only.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the elements are simply reversed. You can do this without additional arrays, with whatever implementation of the swap that you feel like using:

```
int b = 0, e = array.length-1;
while (b < e) {
    array.swap(b, e);
    b = b + 1;
    e = e - 1;
}
```

For integers you can use "[storageless swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3262409/335858)" by computing a sum and subtracting, by XORing, etc. One would never do that in production, though - it's a useless interview trick invented at the time when hardware engineers doubled as programmers more often than they do now (I saw this problem formulated in terms of hardware logical gates some 25 years ago).

Comment: "Not to use any additional **variable** or collections etc"