# How to swap without a third variable?

Tags: c#, variables

I have to swap two variables with a number value without using a third variable. What is the simple solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap the values of two variables without using third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756750/swap-the-values-of-two-variables-without-using-third-variable). Also [Swap two variables without using a temp  variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable

Comment: @Will I've seen some use things like these as trick questions during interviews. I don't know what it's meant to *prove*, but I've seen it..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let us see one of the method namely by using arithmetic operators. 
Consider 2 variables say x=50 and y=70 and let us see how to swap the value of two variables that is make x=70 and y=50 without using third variable. This can be done by using following arithmetic operations namely 

x= x + y 

y= x - y 

x= x - y 

Which gives 

•   x= x + y gives x= 70 + 50 an so x is equal to 120 

•   y= x - y gives y = 120 - 70 which makes the value of y as 50 

•   x= x - y gives x= 120 - 50 and thus value of x becomes 70

Comment: What if x or y was very large in proportion to the other?

Comment: that's a good solution, but have to be careful with overflows

Comment: Answer `x -= y = (x += y) - y;` and tell the teacher that's one of the lamest questions ever.

Comment: @Amadan Except when people use things like these as trick questions during interviews, as if that actually proved anything... :/

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve it with XOR

```
int A = ...;
int B = ...;
A = A ^ B;
B = A ^ B;
A = A ^ B;
```

Comment: @Bertrand, I just made a "mind test" and still believe it's ok. If A equals B, in the first assignment, the result of A would be 0, then B is assigned 0 XOR B which is B, and then A is assigned 0 XOR B which is B again (which was equal to the starting A).

Comment: A=1, B=1. Step 1: A=A^B=1^1=0.  Step2: B=A^B=0^1=1.  Step3: A=A^B=0^1=1.  Looks like it works to me.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the type of variable, you can use [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange.aspx).  This uses an atomic operation to do the swap.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int x = 15;
 int y = 5;

 x = x + y;
 y = x - y;
 x = x - y;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another popular way is the XOR swapping strategy. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Here we have this in [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set) assembler. The first solution is long and bad. The second one with XOR is better.

```
addi $t0, $0, -5
addi $t1, $0, 15

add $t0, $t0, $t1
sub $t1, $t1, $t0
nor $t1, $0, $t1
addi $t1, $t1, 1
sub $t0, $t0, $t1

####

xor $t0, $t0, $t1
xor $t1, $t0, $t1
xor $t0, $t0, $t1
```