# Convert septet to octet in php

Tags: php

I need to convert septets to octest like [this c example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/349719/conversion-from-septets-to-octets):

```
private void septetToOctet()
{
    int len = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int septetcount = septet.Count;

    while (j < septet.Count - 1)
    {
        string tmp = septet[j]; // storing jth value
        string tmp1 = septet[j + 1]; //storing j+1 th value
        string mid = SWAP(tmp1);
        tmp1 = mid;
        tmp1 = tmp1.Substring(0, len);
        string add = SWAP(tmp1);
        tmp = add + tmp;// +"-";
        tmp = tmp.Substring(0, 8);
        //txtoctet.Text += tmp + " || ";
        octet.Add(tmp);
        len++;
        if (len == 8)
        {
            len = 1;
            j = j + 1;
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
}
```

..only problem is - i need to do it in php. Does anybody have an code example for this ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a Q&A site where people help each other to solve particular problems in their code, but it's not a free code writing service. Please have a go at translating the code to PHP yourself, and if there is a particular part you get stuck on, post a question with a clear example of what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code can be translated to PHP with little changes. For instance, the first two assignments would be just `$len = 1` and `$j = 0`. There is no strong static typing in PHP.

Since numbers and strings are scalars in PHP, you cannot call methods on them, so you cannot do `tmp1.substring` but would have to do [`substr($tmp1, …)`.](http://php.net/substr)

septet and octet would be [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/arrays). Again, there is no methods on arrays in PHP. To add to an array, you simply do `$octet[] = $tmp`. To count the elements you do [`count($septet)`](http://php.net/count).

There is no `SWAP` in PHP, but you can derive the rather trivial function from [Is there a built in swap function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862136/is-there-a-built-in-swap-function-in-c)

These hints should get you closer to a working implementation.