# Swap 2 variables with XOR in one line in C#/JS

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to swap 2 variables with an XOR operation.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

This code works in Objective-C and C++, but doesn't work in C# and JavaScript, and I can't understand the reason.

Comment: Because they're not the same language?

Comment: Because in js its way more beautiful (`([a, b] = [b, a]);`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap without a third variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344837/how-to-swap-without-a-third-variable)

Comment: @JonasW. Is there a destructuring operator in C#/C++/C ? If not, then its not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with a slight difference in how C/C++ handle the op-assignment ( +=, ^= and others) operator compared to C# / Javascript.

In Javascript the variable(s) being assigned to do not change value until after the statement is completed. To simplify the math, suppose we have this code in Javascript:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 4;
a += b += a += b;
```

In javascript this sets a = 18 (a = 5 + 4 + 5 + 4) and b = 13 (b = 5 + 4 +  4). This is because of the fact that no variables change values until the whole statement has completed.

In contrast, in C/C++ variable assignment takes places when each subexpression of += takes place. Consider corresponding C code:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
a += b += a += b;
```

This gives a = 22, which is obtained as follows: First the last part of the expression, a += b, is evaluated. This results in the value of 9. then b+= 9 is evaluated, giving b = 13. Then a+= 13 is evaluated giving a = 22.
The value of b stands at 13.

Comment: There is no C/C++, and the code from OP is incorrect in most of the relevant standards, regardless of whether it appears to work.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I do not agree that the code from OP is incorrect, it compiles without warning in some compilers (see for example https://onlinegdb.com/SJ-XSaaVQ ). From C/C++ perspective this is perfectly valid, although a bit terse and perhaps not very transparent. I found the question interesting, it is not obviously apparent why this behaviour is different across these languages.

Comment: @FridjonGudjohnsen It does not compile without waring if you use the right compiler and the right settings: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QOoFLGPw5PxMGETL It's certainly undefined behavior in C++03 and C++11 too I think. C++17 is unclear, and for C I lack the domain knowledge in the newer standards. Certainly not legal C90 though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think this demonstrates a difference in C/C++ languages compared to C# / JavaScript and Java. C/C++ has for example ++a and --a operator that modifies variables before it's containing expression is evaluated. The same effect is in place with the += or ^= operators. BTW Op stated this to work in Objective C and it does compile there without warning.

Comment: @FridjonGudjohnsen Sure it does demonstrate a difference. But your claim that "this gives a = 22" and the explanation following it are still bogus for most standards (at least; I'm not even sure that changed for any standard). If you do this, the behavior of the *entire* program becomes undefined. 22 is as valid of a result as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try [using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

the chained assignments confuses C# and JS

Comment: this variant is working for sure, I just wanted to understand why the variant I wrote wasnt working in C# and JS