# Sorting an array Question

Tags: c

I am using Turbo C, and I've some query about my code. I'm just perplexed... The program first asks for a list of numbers(you shouldn't type more than 20). As the user types in the numbers, they are placed in the array `list[]`. Once the user terminates the list by typing 0*(which is not placed on the list)*, the program then calls the `sort()` function, which sorts the values in the list. At the last part, which has a comment of `/*I AM NOW CONFUSED WITH THIS PART*/`, is the part where I need your help... Kindly help me out.

[image]

```
       File   Edit   Run   Compile   Project   Options   Debug   Break/watch
    ╒════════════════════════════════════ Edit ════════════════════════════════════╕
    │      Line 1     Col 43  Insert Indent Tab Fill Unindent * C:NONAME.C         │
    │                                                                              │
    │ #define MAXSIZE 20                            /* size of buffter */          │
    │ void sort(int[], int);                        /* prototype */                |
    │                                                                              |
    │ main()                                                                       |
    │ {                                                                            |
    │     static int list[MAXSIZE];                 /* buffer for numbers */       |
    │     int size = 0;                             /* size 0 before input */      |
    │     int dex;                                  /* index of array */           |
    │     do                                        /* get list of numbers */      |
    │     {                                                                        |
    │         printf("Type number: ");                                             |
    │         scanf("%d", &list[size]);                                            |
    │     }                                                                        |
    │     while(list[size++] != 0);                 /* exit loop on 0 */           |
    │                                                                              |
    │     sort(list,--size);                        /* sort nubmers */             |
    │     for(dex=0; dex<size; dex++)               /* print sorted list */        |
    │         printf("%d\n", list[dex]);                                           |
    │                                                                              |
    │      getche();                                                               |
    │ }                                                                            |
    │                                                                              |
    │ void sort(int list[], int size)                                              |
    │ {                                                                            |
    │     int out, in, temp;                        /* I AM NOW CONFUSED */        |
    │                                                                              |
    │     for(out=0; out<size-1; out++)             /* IN THIS PART! */            |
    │         for(in=out; in<size; in++)                                           |
    │              if(list[out] > list[in])                                        |
    │              {                                                               |
    │                  temp=list[in];                                              |
    |                  list[in]=list[out];                                         |
    │                  list[out]=temp;                                             |
    │              }                                                               |
    │ }                                                                            |
    │                                                                              |
    │                                                                              |
    ├─────────────────────────────────── Watch ────────────────────────────────────┤
    │                                                                              │
    └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
     F1-Help  F5-Zoom  F6-Switch  F7-Trace  F8-Step  F9-Make  F10-Menu   NUM
```

Comment: please show me what's wrong...

Comment: This just looks like a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), though it isn't doing the swapping correctly.

Comment: Heh, I thought someone _else_ left the `please show me what's wrong` comment, it's hard to _guess_ what's wrong... :)

Comment: @bdares I'm just asking for a help how 2 correctly construct the code...

Comment: I _think_ you might be having trouble with `size` -- does it represent the count of objects in your array, or does it represent the largest index that has been assigned? Think about how a _single number_ would be stored in your array. What would the value of `size` be? How would that influence your `sort()` loop?

Comment: @sarnold It's not the size; it's the swapping as other answers have listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just code that is meant to sort the array elements but it's never going to work in its current form since:

```
temp=list[in];
list[out]=temp;
```

will overwrite `list[out]` with `list[in]` *without ever preserving* the original contents of `list[out]`.

The best way to swap two variables is with something like:

```
temp = array[index1];
array[index1] = array[index2];
array[index2] = temp;
```

And, please, for the love of whatever deity you believe in, don't do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable) :-)

So, if your question is how to sort the data, then the following pseudo-code should help. I'd provide C code but, on the off chance that this is homework, you should do some of the work yourself <sup>a</sup>.

```
def sort (arr[], sz):
    swapped = true                       # Force loop entry.
    while swapped:                       # Loop until a pass had no swaps.
        swapped = false
        for idx goes from 1 to sz-1:     # For all but the first element.
            if arr[idx-1] > arr[idx]:    # If order is wrong.
                swapped = true           # More passes will be needed.
                temp = arr[idx-1]        # Swap
                arr[idx-1] = arr[idx]    #   the
                arr[idx] = temp          #     elements.
```

This is a bubble sort variation which exits as soon as the list is sorted (well, after one pass with no swaps). Some naive variants will simply keep going for roughly `n2` times regardless.

---

<sup>a</sup> If you'd like to indicate in a comment that it's *not* homework, I'd be happy to provide the C code. Just be aware (if you're planning to lie to me) that your educators will almost certainly be able to see that code and you will probably fail in that case (or be expelled for blatant plagiarism).

---

And, since you've stated it's not homework, here's a complete C program illustrating it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE (1==0)
#define TRUE  (1==1)

static void sort (int arr[], int sz) {
    int idx, temp, swapped;

    swapped = TRUE;                        // Force loop entry.
    while (swapped) {                      // Loop until a pass had no swaps.
        swapped = FALSE;
        for (idx  = 1; idx < sz; idx++) {  // For all but the first element.
            if (arr[idx-1] > arr[idx]) {   // If order is wrong.
                swapped = TRUE;            // More passes will be needed.
                temp = arr[idx-1];         // Swap
                arr[idx-1] = arr[idx];     //   the
                arr[idx] = temp;           //     elements.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sz, i, *vals;

    sz = argc - 1;
    if (sz < 1)
        return 0;
    if ((vals = malloc (sz * sizeof (int))) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        vals[i] = atoi (argv[i+1]);

    printf ("Numbers before:");
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf (" %d", vals[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    sort (vals, sz);

    printf ("Numbers after :");
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf (" %d", vals[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    free (vals);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this with:

```
$ ./testprog 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9
```

gives you the output:

```
Numbers before: 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9
Numbers after : 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 8 9 9
```

Comment: @paxdiablo no, it's not homework... We'v not yet reached the date of school starting...

Comment: @paxdiablo... I have modified my code, and it really works. But I have some additional question. In the line `for(out=0; out<size-1; out++)` I tried to remove the -1 like this one `for(out=0; out<size; out++)` and these two were actually working in turn. But I just want to be more accurate(which one is accurate). What happened when I omit the -1? I'm just trying to figure it out... Thanks in advance

Comment: @paxdiable... I put that `-1` because I think, It should exclude the 0 that the user typed in to terminate the program... but I already decremented the `size` in the function call `sort(list,--size);`.

Comment: @aerohn, normally you would detect a sentinel value like zero _before_ trying to place it in the array, something like `val = getval(); while (val != 0) { arr[idx++] = val; val = getval(); }`.

Comment: @paxdiablo, can i ask you something about the pointer notation? How can I change this array notation `scanf("%d", &list[size]);`, into pointer notation? should it be like this `scanf("%d", list+size);`? When we declare an array, the **address name** would be its name itself `list`. And when we increment it, let say `list+2`, the `list` array will be incremented by 4 bytes, since it's integer. But what this runtime messages are?: `"floating point formats not linked" "Abnormal program termination"`

Comment: @aerohn, yes, `&(list[size])` and `list+size` should come down to the same address. The `floating point formats not linked`-type errors are usually in systems where floating-point support is optional (eg, embedded systems) and/or in a separate library to the main stuff. I wouldn't expect to see that unless you'd used a floating point format string like `%f`. Changing the addresses rather than the format string shouldn't cause that. Are you sure you haven't included a floating point converter somewhere?

Comment: @paxdiablo oh... you're right, I've included a floating point. I'm just exploring how to use the pointer. But what if I'm gonna make a program that will accept a floating point format like this `("%f", &list[size])`? If this is incorrect `("%f", list+size)`, what would be the right syntax then?

Comment: @aerohn, both those should be fine since they resolve to the same address. I prefer the former myself. You'll just have to make sure the array is an array of floating point rather than integer, and ensure you link in any extra libraries required.

Comment: @paxdiablo: **make sure the array is an array of floating point rather than integer**; I am getting confused, how can I assure that the array is of floating point, when it was already initialized as a float? If I'm not mistaken, this is how we initialize an array-- `float list[40];`. Then what are those extra libraries required in order to get it done?

Comment: @aerohn, that declaration is correct. However, if you receive a message like `floating point formats not linked` during compilation, the floating point stuff isn't being included by default - you need to do this yourself. From memory (and this is _deep dark_ memeory so I may be mis-remembering), Turbo C will do this if you simply force a floating point operation, like `float f = 1.1 / 1.0;` in the code.

Comment: @aerohn, as the first statement is main, I would suggest. If you really want to make this useful, I'd suggest opening up a new question since this little snippet of information would be quite handy to other Turbo C developers. Comments aren't really built for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The value swap in the inner-most loop of `sort()` is incomplete.  It never assigns `list[in]` to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you are trying to do. Essentially you are trying to find the minimum element at each inner loop iteration. 
For instance, if you start with the array [5,4,3,2,1], after the first inner loop iteration, the array would look like the following:

[5,4,3,2,1] : after in = 0

[4,5,3,2,1] : after in = 1

[3,5,4,2,1] : after in = 2

[2,5,4,3,1] : after in = 3

[1,5,4,3,2] : after in = 4

Now 1 is at the beginning. Eventually, the array would be sorted as [1,2,3,4,5].

```
void sort(int list[], int size) {
    int out, in, temp;       
    for(out=0; out<size; out++)  {        |
        for(in=out; in<size; in++)                                           
            if(list[out] > list[in])                                        
            {                                                               
                tmp = list[out]
                list[out]=list[in];
                list[in] = tmp                                                                                           
            }    
    }                                                           
}
```

Comment: How about the last entered 0 to terminate the program?

Comment: @aerohn you can call sort with sort(list, size - 1) and that would solve your problem.