# Returning the other argument of 2 possible arguments without using conditions

Tags: java

For example, if I have a function that is guaranteed to receive either 5 or 7 as an argument, I want the function to return 5 if received 7 and 7 if received 5 without using any conditions.

I was asked this in an interview and was pretty stumped,
thanks.

Comment: While I think this is a good interview problem, as it gauges the interviewees ability to quick solve simple problems, I don't think this is a great question for this site - it is both trivial and useless.  I'm voting to close as 'too localized'.

Comment: I just realized it's only a rephrased "swap without temp" question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable?lq=1

Comment: It should have been posted on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `Stumped` is the correct answer, as they want to employ someone who writes code that is plain and obvious-to-the-reader, rather than peppering it with im-smarter-than-you snares at every return.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Simple arithmetic:

`return 7 - input + 5;`

(which can be simplified as `return 12 - input;`)

Let's say the input is 7:

return 7 - 7 + 5 --> return 5

Or if the input is 5:

return 7 - 5 + 5 --> return 7

Comment: +1, Even `return 12 - input`

Comment: That's incredible!
Could you share the thought process behind this?

Comment: Nope, just math ;)

Comment: @PremGenError It's not amazing, it's mathematics! Which... of course can be quite amazing sometimes :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg true... :)

Comment: What if the input isn't numeric? I read the question as "two arguments of any type". What if they're strings or dates instead?

Comment: @RyanStewart Considering it's guaranteed to be either 5 or 7, I just assumed it was integer. Otherwise, you could just convert it to integer -- which, isn't using any conditions and thus following the rules.

Comment: @RyanStewart But of course, if you at compile time did not know which type of input is sent, then I think you'd be pretty much screwed if you want it to work for **any** type. And I can not think of any general solution for the parameters `Object a, Object b` without using conditions.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Not at all (on the "screwed" bit). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15056754/839646).

Comment: Great for those occasions when the "i" and "f" and '=' keys aren't functioning properly :)

Answer (score 73):

You can use any simple commutative calculation that can be reversed:

- addition: `f(x)=7+5-x`
- xor: `f(x)=7^5^x`
- multiplication: `f(x)=7*5/x`

Comment: How does the xor one work?

Comment: The reverse of xor is also xor. In each example, x will cancel one of the terms, leaving the other one as the result.

Comment: how would the xor be written in java code?
simple return 7^5^x ?

Comment: Yes that's right. You can also replace 7^5 with its result (2).

Comment: Beware that you can generalize the multiplication approach if and only if _a_ and _b_ (instead of _5_ and _7_) both are nonzero.

Comment: Reminds me of how to swap 2 numbers without a temporary! Use XOR.

Comment: +1 For realising you don't need a line.  You could also use .. a cubic polynomial, trigonometric functions, any function you can dream up which passes through 2 points (5,7) and (7,5)

Answer (score 34):

```
public int f(int x) {
    return x ^ 2;
}
```

In binary:

```
7 = 111
5 = 101
2 = 010
```

XOR (^ in java) flips the 2 bit on if it's off and off if it's on.

Comment: an explanation would be great!
thanks

Comment: This is basically the same as my 2nd example, because 2 = 7 ^ 5

Comment: @user2105338 `^` = XOR operator. Look up that and you might learn more.

Comment: @aditsu, thanks. I was thinking I had to worry about the higher order bits for some reason.

Comment: +1 This is the best solution in my opinion, and was probably what the interviewer was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
public int q(int in)
{
    static final int[] ret = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 5};
    return ret[in];
}
```

Comment: +1 for un-regarding space complexity .. :)

Comment: this is a great answer! loving it

Comment: +1 Good answer and simple.

Answer (score 10):

If I had been the one interviewing and you solved it only for numeric input, my next question would have been, "How would you solve this problem for non-numeric input?" because I wouldn't be looking for mathematical cleverness. Instead, how about this?

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bob", "fred"));
options.remove("bob");
System.out.println(options.get(0));
```

That can obviously be easily adapted to any type, including `Object`, so long as the equality of the objects works out correctly, and as a bonus, it can be expressed much more concisely in other languages, such as Groovy:

```
println((["bob", "fred"] - "bob").first())
```

The output, in either case, is obviously "fred". If I were the one interviewing, this is the answer I'd be looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure remove() uses a condition, but I'm not sure if that would be considered breaking the rules or not

Comment: At least the Groovy version is breaking the rules, since at least in all programming languages I know of, `it != "bob"` is a condition.

Comment: @Simon: True. I was thinking of "conditional" rather than "condition". But I didn't put what I meant to there, anyway. Fixed it.

Comment: @user2105338: That's not what the question says. It says "without using conditions". There are no conditions in my code (except for the original Groovy snippet, which I corrected).

Comment: I like the answer, but my interpretation of "without using any conditions" does not allow usage of a method that uses conditions.

Comment: @user2105338: Basically, solving the problem this way shows that you can solve problems by manipulating common data structures, which is a useful thing to have in a developer. What does it show if you come up with a mathematical trick that only solves the problem for numbers?

Comment: @Simon: To me, "without using any conditions" translates to "in a functional style", aka: "I want to see if your mind is stuck in a single paradigm." Isn't that a more useful thing to know about a job candidate than how his math skills are?

Comment: using math is a way to avoid thinking in the "single paradigm" (that is: avoid the traditional if-else in this case). I believe there are many programmers (like the OP himself) that does not think about using math in a situation like this. Although they are probably even less that think of a solution like yours :)

Comment: @Simon: "Math" isn't a [Programming Paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm). I'm talking about functional vs. imperative. The phrasing sounds exactly like that kind of question.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I also noticed you got a downvote. Even though I don't think this was what the interviewer was looking for, I do think it is a helpful and informational answer and will give you an upvote for it.

Comment: @Simon: Downvotes are part of life around here :) It doesn't bother me much, except that there was no accompanying comment. I'm not trying to be difficult. I learn from this place, so I try to contribute back alternate (and sometimes controversial!) points of view that will make people think :) Thanks!

Comment: @RyanStewart I don't think the question was solely about mathematical cleverness. It's probably a question to see if the candidate knows about bitwise operation which is quite complex that beginners tend to avoid (even the experienced ones!) but if learned correctly can give you elegant solutions. It is also a good indicator of a candidate's analytical skills. Now, using objects as inputs will defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 8):

```
public int xyz(int x) {
    return 35 / x;
}
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is good, I like this one more, because I would not think about it. I immediately thought about `7 MOD input + 5` :)

Comment: public int xyz(int x) {
    return (12- x);
}

Answer (score 7):

> How does the xor one work? [for case f(x) = 7^5^x ]

XOR (^) is Exclusive OR and works this way

```
a|b|a^b
-------
0|0| 0
0|1| 1
1|0| 1
1|1| 0
```

So XOR (^) can be used to change bits of some number. For example when we want to change last two bits of any number (like `xxxx10` to `xxxx01`) we can do it with `numbrer ^ 3` since 3 is binary 00011.

Here are few facts about XOR

1. XOR is symmetric -> `a^b` = `b^a`
2. XOR is associative -> `(a^b)^c` = `a^(b^c)`
3. `a^a` = `0` (ones in `a` will be replaced with zeros and zeros will be not changed)

   example for a = 157 (binary 010011101)

   ```
     010011101
   ^ 010011101
   -----------
     000000000
   ```
4. `0^a` = `a` (ones in `a` can only change zeros so they will change them to ones)

   ```
     000000000
   ^ 010011101
   -----------
     010011101
   ```

so using facts (1) and (2) `7^5^x == x^7^5 == x^5^7`

Lets try to check how `x^7^5` will work **for `x=7`.**

```
(x^7)^5 = (7^7)^5 = 0^5 = 5
```

And same happens **for `x=5`**

```
(x^5)^7 = (5^5)^7 = 0^7 = 7
```