# How to swap two variables of different types in C#?

Tags: c#

How to swap two variables in C#?

i.e.:

```
var a = 123;
var b = "hello!";

swap(a, b); // hypothetical

System.Console.WriteLine(a);
System.Console.WriteLine(b);
```

outputs:

> hello!
>
> 123

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable

Comment: Not exactly same, there is same type (decimal)

Comment: You can't. Implicit typing (using var) is still strongly typed. So a is an `int` and b is a `string` and you can't store a `string` in an `int` and vice-versa.

Comment: use `object` instead of `var` then you can

Comment: @user2160380 - Yes, you should definitely switch to javaScript. Or VBA.

Comment: I believe it is a great feature. There are different set of functions to work with with different type of variable. It would difficult to debug when we sometimes unsure of what is true identity of your variable.

Comment: How is this "not constructive"? This question is both real and constructive; perhaps it's a duplicate, but the one linked in a comment misses a twist of a type difference. Nominating for re-opening.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it with variables of different type. When the variables are of the same type, the simplest way is the "naive" implementation with a `temp`:

```
var temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

You can wrap this into a `swap` method that takes its parameters by reference:

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) {
    var temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

You cannot change the type of a statically typed variable (`var` uses a static type determined at compile time). You can declare your variable as `object` or `dynamic` if the type of a variable must change at runtime. In case you do it, however, the value types (including `int`s) will be wrapped in reference types.

Comment: Would not work with different types (int and string) like OP demonstrated in his question however.

Comment: What about predefined types? Can I change type of variable dynamically?

Comment: @user2160380: No, you can't. C# is a strongly typed language.

Comment: @user2160380 No, you cannot change the type of a variable. If you need the type to change at runtime, you can declare your variable `dynamic`.

Comment: 'var' is not a "changing" type.  It's a shortcut to let the compiler decide the data type.  Your variable `b` is a `string`, even though you say `var`.  Your variable `a` is an int, even though you say `var`.  You cannot assign "Hello!" to an `int`.

Comment: @MattHouser The answer already says that about `var`.

Comment: +1. Side note: `object` is perfectly valid "predefined type" and can be used to make this type of code work... Same with `dynamic` for duck typed languages lowers.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I was in the process of adding this info. The the answer is explicit about it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `var`.

If you really needed to do something like that, you could use `dynamic` and your typical implementation of a swap with temp:

```
dynamic a = 123;
dynamic b = "hello!";
var temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Comment: Dynamic could be a bit overkill but it will work definitely.

Comment: @dandrejvv Other than declaring them with `object`, `dynamic` is the only way to do what the OP wants. It has the added benefit of not needing to cast whenever you need the specific type. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/01/25/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords.aspx) for more info on dynamic vs. object.

Answer (score 1):

```
object varA = 123;
object varB = "hello!";
object temp = varA;
varA = varB;
varB = temp;
```

That should work with different types for all .NET versions (I think).