# Swap two numbers without using another variable

Tags: c#

Swap two variables without using a temp variable 
if

```
int a=4; 
int b=3;
```

I need to swap these variable and get output as 
 a=3 and b=4
without using another variable in C#

Comment: Any particular reason?  I would have thought 3 MSIL **assignments** (`t = a; a=b; b=t; )` to be faster than **3 MSIL operations** followed by **3 assignments** judging by the answers below?

Comment: @MickyDuncan The speed is completely irrelevant here. There is no way anyone could have sat down to optimize their code and discovered the bottleneck was an extra statement when swapping two values.

Comment: @Asad So is arguably wanting to swap two variables without impacting the heap.  This question represents questionable benefit

Comment: @MickyDuncan This is a rather typical interview question.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thanks.  Yes for `floating-point` it is quite important.

Comment: **paxdiablo's** answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable) makes a good point.  _"developers who try to use tricks to, for example, swap variables without using a temp or 'Duff's device' are just trying to show how clever they are"_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the following concept

```
int a=4 ;
int b=3 ;

a=a+b ;  //  a=7
b=a-b ;  //  b=7-3=4
a=a-b ;  //  c=7-4=3
```

Answer (score 7):

Use **Interlocked.Exchange**()

```
int a = 4;
int b = 3;

b = Interlocked.Exchange(ref a, b);
```

### Tell me more

From MSDN:

> Sets a 32-bit signed integer to a specified value as an atomic operation, and then returns the original value

**EDIT:** Regarding Esoteric's fine link above (thank-you), there's even a **Interlocked.Exchange**() for `double` that may help there too.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually a couple of ways.

The following is considered an [obfuscated swap](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/obfuscated-swaps).

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Works the same with any language.

Comment: Just watch out for overflow :p

Answer (score 1):

Using addition and subtraction

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Using xor operator

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/25/xor-trick/