# Swapping array with the XOR operator doesn’t work in Python

Tags: python, xor

I was trying to code Quicksort in Python (see the full code at the end of the question) and in the partition function I am supposed to swap two elements of an array (call it `x`). I am using the following code for swapping based on the xor operator:

```
x[i]^=x[j]
x[j]^=x[i]
x[i]^=x[j]
```

I know that it should work because of the nilpotence of the xor operator (i.e. `x^x=0`) and I have done it like a million times in Java and in C without any problem. My question is: why doesn’t it work in Python? It seems that it is not working when `x[i] == x[j]` (maybe `i = j`?).

```
x = [2,4,3,5,2,5,46,2,5,6,2,5]
print x
def part(a,b):
  global x
  i = a
  for j in range(a,b):
    if x[j]<=x[b]:
      x[i]^=x[j]#t = x[i]
      x[j]^=x[i]#x[i] = x[j]
      x[i]^=x[j]#x[j]=t
      i = i+1
  r = x[i]
  x[i]=x[b]
  x[b]=r
  return i
def quick(y,z):
  if z-y<=0:
    return
  p = part(y,z)
  quick(y,p-1)
  quick(p+1,z)
quick(0,len(x)-1)
print x
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you getting wrong output? If so you should include that in the question.

Comment: Those 3 lines do work, so the problem is somewhere else. But as paxdiablo said in his answer, you shouldn't be swapping like that.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks for asking. My question is why it does not work. If i use the xor swap i get
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 6, 46]
and if i use the commented code i get
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 46]

Comment: @Cyphase Thanks for replying, it is there the problem. I use the commented swapping and it works.

Comment: @user16117, that's very strange; I'm not running your exact code, but `d=[1,2]; d[0]^=d[1];d[1]^=d[0];d[0]^=d[1]` works for me; `d` will be `[2,1]`.

Comment: @user16117, ah, I think it is because `i == j`, as you mentioned it might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to why it doesn't work, it really shouldn't matter<sup>1</sup>, because you [shouldn't be using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable/805098#805098) code like that in the first place, *especially* when Python gives you a perfectly good 'atomic swap' capability:

```
x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

It's always been my opinion that all programs should be initially optimised for readability first and only have performance or storage improvements imposed if there's a clear need and a clear benefit (neither of which I've ever seen for the XOR trick outside some incredibly small data environments like some embedded systems).

Even in languages that *don't* provide that nifty feature, it's more readable and probably faster to use a temporary variable:

```
tmp = x[i]
x[i] = x[j]
x[j] = tmp
```

---

<sup>1</sup> However, if you *really* want to know why it's not working, it's because that trick is okay for swapping two *distinct* variables, but not so well when you use it with the *same* variable, which is what you'll be doing when you try to swap `x[i]` with `x[j]` when `i` is equal to `j`.

It's functionally equivalent to the following, with `print` statements added so you can see where the whole thing falls apart:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> a ^= a ; print(a)
0
>>> a ^= a ; print(a)
0
>>> a ^= a ; print(a)
0
```

Contrast that with two *distinct* variables, which works okay:

```
>>> a = 314159; b = 271828; print(a,b)
314159 271828

>>> a ^= b; print(a,b)
61179 271828

>>> b ^= a; print(a,b)
61179 314159

>>> a ^= b; print(a,b)
271828 314159
```

The problem is that the trick works by transferring information between the two variables gradually (similar to the [fox/goose/beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle) puzzle). When it's the *same* variable, the first step doesn't so much transfer information as it does destroy it.

Both Python's 'atomic swap' and use of a temporary variable will avoid this problem completely.

Comment: Yes, your last update for now, it is really what is about the question, so, why can we explain that behavior? it's weird, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks for answering paxdiablo. Why it should not matter? I am not a native python coder and i am not used to those expressions. I get it works like that and i am thankful about the knowledge but, for me, it matters why/how things works and why/how they do not.

Comment: @user16117 If you take `xor` for any number with same number, it will give you a zero. Then how can you reproduce same number from zero?

Comment: @niyasc Ah 0k, i get it now. I was using exactly the same variable. Thanks :)

Comment: @niyasc, the problem isn't that the numbers are the same, it's that `x[i]` and `x[j]` are referring to the same variable. `x[i]` can be equal to `x[j]`, as long as `i` is not equal to `j`.

Comment: @niyasc, yea, `x ^ x == 0`, but try doing `a = 42; b = 42; a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b`. It works; meaning, `(a, b) == (42, 42)`.

Comment: @Cyphase; Ok I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I was reviewing this fact, and for example, you could express the xor like the following expression:

```
a xor b = (a or b) - (a & b)
```

So, basically, if you replace a by b, Whoa! xDD
You'll get it, zero.